# Accidentaly deleted some files in var/lib

Tags: terminal, var, ubuntu-18.04, lib

I accidentally deleted some files in var/lib. I don't know what I have deleted. Terminal too then disappeared since I messed up with Gnome-Purge. I then reinstalled terminal using TTY. But then when I try to install some package, Unmet dependencies 'Try apt-fix broken install' with no package name. I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu.
Also I tried `sudo apt-get install -f. It returned:[image]

I was able to find what packages are corrupt by doing `sudo dpkg -C`. The result is:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop metapackage:

```
sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get build-dep ubuntu-desktop
```

This will install again all the base system and dependencies without needing to format your computer. If you're using a flavor such as Xubuntu, just replace ubuntu-desktop with the corresponding metapackage, like xubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, etc.

Comment: first thing, you've missed a '-' before the reinstall command in the first statement. 
And that returned: 
`You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install to correct these`
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl(=9.0.1-2) but 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install` with no packages(or specify a solution).`

And the second command returned:
`E; You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`